# Create Pandas Column from Dictionary of Lists

Tags: pandas, dictionary, calculated-columns

I have looked everywhere but I am not quite getting the answer I am looking for. I am working with a much larger data-set but I have broken this down to a much simpler representation.

I am looking for the most efficient way of creating a pandas column that maps a dictionary where the keys have lists as values.  The code below performs really well when a dictionary has one key and one value.  However, it throws an error with when I change the values to a list.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Dog','Dog',"Cat","John","Steve", 'Steve']})


dic={"Person":['John', 'Steve'], 
     "Animal":["Dog", "Cat"]
}


for i, v in dic.items():
    df.loc[df.col1==i, "new_col"]=v 

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Desired output:

```
    col1   new_col
0   Dog     Animal
1   Dog     Animal
2   Cat     Animal
3   John    Person
4   Steve   Person
5   Steve   Person
```

To be sure, I have been using np.where to do this in the past. Instead of using a dictionary to do the mapping, I use np.where and write each mapping out.  The code below performs well, but with larger transformations (in the hundreds) it becomes cumbersome.  I am looking for the most "pythonic" way of performing this task. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
df["new_col"]=np.where((df.col1=="Dog")|\
                       (df.col1=="Cat"),
                       "Animal", 
                       "Person"
                          )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap keys with values in `dict` and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in dic.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'John': 'Person', 'Steve': 'Person', 'Dog': 'Animal', 'Cat': 'Animal'}

df['new_col'] = df['col1'].map(d)
print (df)
    col1 new_col
0    Dog  Animal
1    Dog  Animal
2    Cat  Animal
3   John  Person
4  Steve  Person
5  Steve  Person
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks!